# Simple pandas Dataframe transformation

Tags: python, pandas

Venturing into python using some pandas. I'm trying to some very simple transformations on a Dataframe.  Have read thru the docs and am not quite sussing out how this works.  I want a simple subtraction on cells in a row.  Want to return a new Dataframe with the computed column.  Like so:

```
def geMeWhatIwant (data)
    #data is a Dataframe organized like index : col 1 : col2
    return log(data col1 - data col2)
```

It feels like this can be done under the hood without iterating over the Dataframe in my function.  If I need to iterate then so be it.  Could itterrows thru and do computations and append to return Dataframe.  I'm simply looking for the most efficient and elegant way to do this in python - pandas

Thanks

Comment: your syntax seems incorrent...

Comment: Yeah, you should access values by using square brackets. `data[col1]`, for example.
Where do you get the `log` function, btw?

Comment: It' just psudo code.  I could post the things i've been hacking on but they'd add nothing.  I can (not-elegant) simply iterate and do the computations line by line but that seems simplistic and not good practice.  Trying to learn the good patterns.  Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should work:

```
import numpy as np

np.log(df[col1] - df[col2])
```

Comment: Thank you.  Yes, that works perfectly.  Forgot about looking upstream.

Comment: No problem. The reason you don't need to use a loop is because of broadcasting. It's one of the great features of pandas, look it up! Also, please consider validating the answer if it helped :)